# How to make google auto login functionality in Spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-oauth

I have applied google login functionality in my spring project.  which functions like-- a user login in with google account the details of user saved into database.  But, I have a requirement to auto login google account user who previously logged in with the account. but I don't know how to do that.
One way to do that (what I think) is to save cookie, but after that how a user logged in using that cookie.

I am using Spring Security Oauth2 got google sign in. After searching I got, openid is used to autologin.  But I don't know how to apply and implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Look into refresh tokens. Once the user been inactive for 2 hours (as by default), his token expires. He can obtain a new one if he has a refresh token, which you can store on your side when you authorize that user.

Comment: i know that refresh token is used to renew access token. but my question is not that.

Comment: I want that if user logged in with their google account and close the session and again return to website the he/she will be automatically be logged in with their previous google account

Comment: Use cookies then

Comment: yes, but how do i know that google acount is loggedIn in the browser

Comment: when the user returns you check if you have a refresh token. If you the user has one, you try to fetch the user object. If you get denied, you try to refresh the token. If the token refresh fails you redirect them to the login page. If it succeeds you know that user is logged in and has a valid token so you assume that they are logged in and show them the page in a logged in state.